# Jquery timepicker addon not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have this code in my view (JS):

```
$("#mydivelement").timepicker();
```

Instead of only timepicker, it displays datetimepicker. I have datepicker defaults set in Layout page if it matters:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        yearRange: '1930:2012',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        autoSize: true,
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        firstDay: 1
    });
```

Update: Used Library- jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Comment: just an idea: why do you set `dateFormat` when you want a timepicker... perhaps that could be the problem.

Comment: It's datepicker defaults, not timepicker

Comment: Oh... sorry, I just didn't read exactly... (now it makes sense) :D

Comment: What `timepicker` library are you using?

Comment: jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing to add `{}` to inside of `.timepicker()`

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#mydivelement" ).datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        yearRange: '1930:2012',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        autoSize: true,
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        firstDay: 1
    });
    $('#timepicker').timepicker({}); // it shows only timepicker without datepicker
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/f9xc7/3/)

Comment: does not work in ie9 :( but works in chrome. Do you know why?

Comment: Could you try it again? i updated it. just forgot to delete `,` after `firstday: 1`

Comment: No, that's no problem. This line does not work in library: $.fn.datetimepicker.apply($(this), tmp_args);